# Cross Browser Rich Text Editor Control

Tags: web-part, user-controls, field-controls

I may be going crazy over here, but I cannot seem to find a Rich Text/HTML control for SharePoint 2010.

I have successfully implemented an InputFormTextBox, but this only shows up in IE.

I've tried SharePoint:RichTextField and PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField, neither of which seem to show up outside of a list view page.

I just want to have a custom form that saves to multiple lists depending on a user choice that allows the user to input rich text regardless of their browser. I'm about ready to give up and look for jQuery plugins.

What am I missing here?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the jQuery route. You are correc that there is not a good cross browser editor for your situation. Be aware that even with jQuery or other non-SharePoint specific browser based web editors there is still a good chance that the solution will not be completely cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

[CKEditor for ASP.NET](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor.NET_released) - I've not integrated it into SharePoint but a colleague of mine used it in an ASP.NET application. I've been using the editor and its predecessor for years in PHP, as well.